# How can I correctly parse array of JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

this is my data:

```
var data = [ { "_id": "5e458e2ccf9b1326f11b5079", "xxTitle": "testtttttttttttt", "hhhhhhhhhh": "sssssssss", "xxzzzzzz": null, "oooooooooooooo": "ssssss", "xxDescription": "sssssss", "xxDetails": "ssssssss", "lllllllllllllllll": "sssssssssss", "ppppppppppp": null, "__typename": "xx" }, { "_id": "5e4595374bee49300c47e1ab", "xxTitle": "ggggggg", "hhhhhhhhhh": "ggggggg", "xxzzzzzz": "ggggggg", "oooooooooooooo": "ggggggg", "xxDescription": "ggggggg", "xxDetails": "ggggggg", "lllllllllllllllll": "ggggggg", "ppppppppppp": "ggggggg", "__typename": "xx" } ]
```

I want to pass this data as a string via HTTP and then read it back as json, instead I'm getting `[ '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ]`

please assist.

Comment: Try to pass around the string version of the object: `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you already tried (to code / decode the data).

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON.parse to convert your JSON string to a javascript object.

***JSON Object***

```
var data = [ { "_id": "5e458e2ccf9b1326f11b5079", "xxTitle": "testtttttttttttt", "hhhhhhhhhh": "sssssssss", "xxzzzzzz": null, "oooooooooooooo": "ssssss", "xxDescription": "sssssss", "xxDetails": "ssssssss", "lllllllllllllllll": "sssssssssss", "ppppppppppp": null, "__typename": "xx" }, { "_id": "5e4595374bee49300c47e1ab", "xxTitle": "ggggggg", "hhhhhhhhhh": "ggggggg", "xxzzzzzz": "ggggggg", "oooooooooooooo": "ggggggg", "xxDescription": "ggggggg", "xxDetails": "ggggggg", "lllllllllllllllll": "ggggggg", "ppppppppppp": "ggggggg", "__typename": "xx" } ]
```

***JSON String***

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
```

***JSON Object back again***

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse your JSON into a var
In your case it’ll be:

var jsonData = JSON.parse(data)
    var id = jsonData._id